# Border-bottom I can't remove

Tags: html, css, ionic2, ionic3

I'm stuck in IONIC 2 for removing something like a border-bottom on ion-item tag as presented in the picture attached.

[Picture of the border I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyrD8.jpg)

My code is below:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-item class="header-item">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-title>Gallerie</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

And my CSS below:

```
.header-item {
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
    }
```

Have you any idea?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: that is not a border, that is `box-shadow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can see in **[in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/#usage)**, you can use the `no-lines` attribute to remove that line:

```
<ion-item no-lines>
  Item with no border
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, it's perfect! I didn't find the information, I've gone through the doc to quickly.